# I am trying to implement a View Pager with controlled swiping.But I am getting a binary inflate exception on the custom view page

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to disable or enable the Viewpager's from swiping with a custom      Viewpager..But i am getting the inflating exception on the viewpager .Please anyone help me.

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Timer timer;
int page = 0;
ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));


    pager.setEnabled(false);


    //pageSwitcher(3);




}
```

////extending ViewPager class

```
public class HackyViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean enabled;
    public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }




    public HackyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } }
```

## activity_main Xml

### adding a custom viewpager

```
     <com.example.qms.MainActivity.HackyViewPager
     android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="2.5" />


   # Exception #

 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating      
 class com.example.qms.MainActivity.HackyViewPager
```

Comment: check that HackyViewPager is available in the package where you mention in the xml file

Comment: Thanks Younas, the hacky view pager was not available and i changed it to Custom ViewPager..But still I am getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

This could be HackyViewPager is missed in you mentioned package.
Please check if it available.

You can android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.

[View Pager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: How to check if it is available in package..Soryy I am new to Android